# configure: error: Package requirements were not met. But i have already installed those packages in my system

Tags: fedora, configure

```
[root@localhost rpm-ostree]# ./configure 
checking for library containing rpmsqSetInterruptSafety... no
checking for PKGDEP_GIO_UNIX... yes
checking for PKGDEP_RPMOSTREE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gio-unix-2.0 >= 2.40.0 json-glib-1.0
                     ostree-1 >= 2015.1 libgsystem >= 2015.1
                     rpm hawkey libhif >= 0.2.0) were not met:

No package 'json-glib-1.0' found
No package 'ostree-1' found
No package 'libgsystem' found
No package 'rpm' found
No package 'hawkey' found
No package 'libhif' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PKGDEP_RPMOSTREE_CFLAGS
and PKGDEP_RPMOSTREE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

---

```
[root@localhost rpm-ostree]# dnf install rpm hawkey libhif libgsystem ostree json-glib
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:10:52 ago on Mon Oct 26 10:33:32 2015.
Package rpm-4.12.0.1-9.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Package hawkey-0.5.6-1.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Package libhif-0.2.0-3.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Package libgsystem-2015.1-2.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Package ostree-2015.6-2.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Package json-glib-1.0.4-1.fc22.ppc64le is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Comment: Do you perchance have any 3rd party repos enabled?  If you get libraries from a 3rd party repo (such as by running `sudo yum update` with 3rd party repos enabled) you can get weird errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the same class of errors as in the question [Trying to automake gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132220/17535).  You need to install the -devel packages, which contain the header files and library stubs that are necessary for *building* code that uses these libraries.

- [json-glib-devel](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/22/ppc64le/j/json-glib-devel-1.0.4-1.fc22.ppc64le.html)
- [ostree-devel](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/22/ppc64le/ostree-devel-2015.6-2.fc22.ppc64le.html)
- [libgsystem](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/22/ppc64le/l/libgsystem-2015.1-1.fc22.ppc64le.html)
- [rpm-devel](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/updates/22/ppc64le/rpm-devel-4.12.0.1-12.fc22.ppc64le.html)
- [hawkey-devel](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/22/ppc64le/h/hawkey-devel-0.5.6-1.fc22.ppc64le.html)
- [libhif-devel](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/22/ppc64le/l/libhif-devel-0.2.0-3.fc22.ppc64le.html)

In my opinion, the author of the [software you appear to be trying to build](https://github.com/projectatomic/rpm-ostree) should provide an RPM build spec that [declares its build dependencies](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-advanced-packaging.html#id633338), especially since the software is designed to work with RPM.  If the software came with a spec file, then you could just run [`dnf builddep rpm-ostree.spec`](//stackoverflow.com/a/13228992/1157100) then [`rpmbuild -ba rpm-ostree.spec`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#Create_binary_RPMS_from_the_SPEC_file). This is an opportunity for you to make an enhancement request or contribute the RPM packaging.